# When use flex layout, how to make flex row width same

Tags: javascript, css

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--mobile friendly-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <style>
    #container {
      display:flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" >
</div>
<script>
  class App {
    constructor() {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        this.init()
      })
    }

    init() {
      var container = document.querySelector("#container")
      $(container).width()

      function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        let el = $(`<div/>`);
        el.css("background-color", getRandomColor())
        el.width(Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * 100))
        el.css("height", "20vh")
        container.appendChild(el[0])
      }
    }
  }

 new App()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

it's right side has not-same-padding, but I expect it's like google image search page(all rows left and right side padding are same), how to do

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `flex-grow:1` to your items:

```js
class App {
  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      this.init()
    })
  }

  init() {
    var container = document.querySelector("#container")
    $(container).width()

    function getRandomColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      return color;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      let el = $(`<div/>`);
      el.css("background-color", getRandomColor())
      el.width(Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * 100))
      container.appendChild(el[0])
    }
  }
}

new App()
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height:25vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set flex-basis for width of div tag:
`#container  div{
        flex-grow: 0;
       flex-shrink: 1;
       flex-basis: 20%
      }`

then set 100% for width in js:

```
 el.css("width", "100%")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--mobile friendly-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    #container {
      display:flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;

    }
         #container  div{
        flex-grow: 0;
       flex-shrink: 1;
       flex-basis: 20%
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" >
</div>
<script>
  class App {
    constructor() {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        this.init()
      })
    }

    init() {
      var container = document.querySelector("#container")
      $(container).width()

      function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        let el = $(`<div/>`);
        el.css("background-color", getRandomColor())

        el.css("width", "100%")
        el.css("height", "20vh")
        container.appendChild(el[0])
      }
    }
  }

 new App()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  #container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;

      ////////////////
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation